Feasibility of running BLE server and client in parallel on Ubuntu 20.04 (Jetson Xavier NX, Bluetooth v4.2) using BLUEZ
I'm currently exploring the capabilities of Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) using BLUEZ on Ubuntu 20.04, specifically on the (Jetson Xavier NX) platform with Bluetooth version 4.2, for a project. Is it possible to run both a BLE server and client in parallel on this operating system? If so, I would greatly appreciate guidance or steps on how to achieve this. Additionally, are there any potential issues or limitations I should consider when running both server and client roles simultaneously?
Thank you in advance for any assistance or insights provided.
